# How to display an image from a file with a Base64 string with GeekTool?

Tags: image, base64, geektool

My base64 string file is on http://domain.com/image.txt

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

So how can I display this image to my desktop with GeekTool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$img = "t.php";
$fh = fopen($img,'r');
$data = fread($fh,filesize($img ));
fclose($fh);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($data);
?>
```

Now i using PHP :D